# Android: dealing with spanish e accent

Tags: android, diacritics

I am working on an Android app that I would like to code in such a way so that the Spanish characters coming from the database are read as equivalent to the English ones. For instance, `cafe` and `café` would be identical.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want queries to find both "cafe" and "café" when you search for "cafe"?  You should be able to use a regular expressions to do this.

If this needs to be done on the fly, you could write a function that parses the request for 'e' and generate the correct regular expression before creating the DB query.

Comment: I don't want to distinguish between the two versions on cafe...they should be read as the same string.